# security issues analysis via mvn dependency-check:check and better report

Tags: java, maven, security, dependencies, maven-dependency-check-plugin

Within maven project, I can do

```
mvn dependency-check:check
```

for the tools to download NVD CVE security issues database, analyze
and show report, what dependencies have known security issues.

However, as solution would be update several dependencies e.g. via Spring Boot update,
I would like to see how many security issues would be solved that one.
E.g. updating from x.y.5 to x.y.10 will solve n security issues:

Or better for every security issue, what is version that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, so far I have found no better way, then to clone project again,
update some dependencis and run `mvn dependency-check:check` again,
and then copy 1st and 2nd reports in one place and compare.